# Comparison between current year date and previous year same period in Apache Superset

Tags: apache-superset

I am trying to compare current year (selected Date Range >= '2023-01-01' and <= '2023-01-31')
also I need to see result from previous year same (Period) Date Range (>= '2022-01-01' and <= '2022-01-31') using visualization type **Table** .

As I Known superset creates query on every visual which is built in function.

After applying date range filter Current year records are shown in table while Previous year records shown **N/A or Null**.

Is there any way to visualize Current year and Previous year same period in one table in Apache Superset .